# .NET Core 3.1 role-based authorization with JWT returns 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I am having an issue, when I am trying to use `[Authorize(Roles  = "Administrator")]` in my controllers, it always returns `403`. I am using Identity and JWT tokens. Here's my `Startup.cs` . I am calling both `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` in `ConfigureServices()`, but still the same, everytime it returns `403`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;

        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "user_id";
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "email";
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "user_role";
    })
        .AddRoles<Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JwtKey"].ToString());

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Here's how I am creating token

```cs
private async Task<string> GenerateToken(DataModelUser user)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JwtKey);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim("user_role", user.Role.ToString()),
            new Claim("user_id", user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim("email", user.Email)
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
}
```

And I am adding like this on my controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class ProfileController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Here's my JWT token payload!

```
{
  "user_role": "Administrator",
  "user_id": "5a6333f1-9696-4b1c-a8f8-04619ebd686d",
  "name": "Admin Admin",
  "completed_profile": "False",
  "email": "myadminemail@gmail.com",
  "nbf": 1597147248,
  "exp": 1597233648,
  "iat": 1597147248
}
```

Comment: Hi @Erlan. Are you checking for role "Admin" or "Administrator"? Since in the post above you're mentioning to check for "Admin" and in the controller example you're checking for "Administrator".

Comment: @ThomasLuijken sorry, it wrote it wrong, since I'm checking for `Administrator`, edited the question now!

Comment: @Erlan, alright, thanks for the update. Just to check that we didn't miss anything obvious. I would expect setting the 'user_role' claim on both places could do the trick, but apparently it doesn't. Can you upload a part of the payload from the JWT token as well to the ticket so we can see what the actual content of your token looks like? You can just paste in the accestoken at https://jwt.io/ to see the actual payload.

Comment: @ThomasLuijken Yeah sure, just edited question and added payload from JWT token.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I resolved it by adding RoleClaimType and NameClaimType to the TokenValidationParameter:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    RoleClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    NameClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Name
};
```

Comment: Thank you, using RoleClaimType resolved my issue